# Float left breaking the layout

Tags: html, css

i'm little stuck here

https://jsfiddle.net/nap0qs3r/2/embedded/result/

My layout is breaking because i am using the float:left in one paragraphs and in one anchor tag, i already try clear both, but is not working at all.

HTML:

```
<section class="disclaimer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM 
    </p>
    <a href="mailto:reservas@me.com">
        contato
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 4.8%;
    padding-right: 4.8%;
    max-width: 688px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    padding-left: 4.4%;
    padding-right: 4.4%;
    max-width: 1360px;
  }
}
.disclaimer {
  background: #f98835;
  padding-top: 2.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 2.25rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .875rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.disclaimer p {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.disclaimer a {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 620px) {
  .disclaimer p,
  .disclaimer a {
    float: left;
  }
  .disclaimer p {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .disclaimer a {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

What should i do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the clearfix hack which will allow a parent to clear it's children.  Apply the following styles to the parent `<div class="container">`

```
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
```

Here's a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/nap0qs3r/5/

More info on clearfix here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a block(with clear:both css) element after all the floating element.
for eg.

```
    <section class="disclaimer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM LOREM 
    </p>
    <a href="mailto:reservas@me.com">
        contato
    </a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</section>

.clearfix{
 clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make minor change in your css file like this

```
.disclaimer,.container
{
float:left;
}
```